# UI grid get selected row's index

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I wanted the index/index value of the selected row, in ui-grid.
I tried to get it using onRowSelectionChange event. But couldn't able to get it.

Can anyone has any idea about the same ?

Answer (score 4):

There may be a more elegant solution these days, but in the version of ui-grid I was working with some months ago, I used the following service function to get the row index.

```
getRowIndex: function (row, grid) {
    var rowIndex = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache.length; i++) {
        if (row.uid === grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache[i].uid) {
            rowIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return rowIndex;
}
```

You can get the reference to the row from many events, including the `rowSelectionChanged` event.

To get the reference to the grid...

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
}
```

And call

```
var myIndex = myService.getRowIndex(row, $scope.gridApi.grid);
```

Note that this index changes when you re-sort or change the data. It is based on the index of the data as the user sees it.

Answer (score 3):

In controller `grid_options` set:

```
onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
                $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
                gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){
                 var removeRowIndex = $scope.grid_Options.data.indexOf(row.entity);
                });
               }
```

`$scope.grid_Options.data` is actually data which you provided to grid.